# Import a css file?

Tags: sass

I have a sass file that imports all my scss files, I also use bower for some extra stuff, I import these files too. The problem is, one component only has css files, how can I import them into my sass file?

I'm using gulp to compile.

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate, but that question is pretty outdated now.

Comment: No, it is perfectly relevant.  Sass hasn't changed since that question was posted.  The appropriate action is to post a bounty on the original question, not open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a gulp task that moves `example.css` into a temporary build folder as `example.scss`, which makes it importable.

```
fs.createReadStream('vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sweetalert/lib/sweet-alert.css')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('public/css/_sweet-alert.scss'));
```

Comment: Interesting, do you have a code example?

Comment: @panthro Added the snippet.